# Re-using a inputStream for txt file(online) - Java

Tags: java, inputstream

My program reads data from a online txt file. That change a lot of times.

I use a inputStream to read the data, and put it in a ArrayList. Works fine.
But I use the same method with the same inputstream to refresh the arraylist.
And I get the same data.

Class:

```
public class getGameData {

static InputStream is;

public static ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<String> getGameData(String file) {

    URLConnection con;

    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://timme7893.nl/CardGame/GameData.txt");
        con = url.openConnection();
        con.connect();
        is =con.getInputStream();           

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
           // System.out.println(line);
            array.add(line);
        }
        is.close();
        is = null;
        br.close();         
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return array;
}
```

My question: How to clear or refresh the inputstream, so my ArrayList gets the good data?

Comment: Clear the array inside `getGameData`

Comment: Yeah, have a for loop to remove each element from the ArrayList. If you don't want to lose the data, save the ArrayList to a file as you run through your ArrayList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for starters, clear the list. `list.clear();`

or mark the input stream then reset. `is.mark(0); is.reset();`

also analyze this line: `is =con.getInputStream();` it will always get the same input stream.

also as a tip, close your connections in a finally block.

Comment: you optionally persist any data you want before clearing.

Comment: *"which one worked?"* Obviously the first one, the other two are wrong. Resetting a newly created InputStream won't do much and the sentence "it will always get the same input stream" is also wrong. It reads from the same source, yes, but the content is not necessarily equal. Your final advice is correct, though.

Comment: I'm not OP (just to avoid confusion).